# Zend framework form helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to work out how below works...

Where does `Jobs_Form_Report_Productivity()` come from?

```
public function productivityAction(){
        $this->view->headTitle('Number of Unique Jobs by Portfolio');
        $this->view->form = new Jobs_Form_Report_Productivity();

        if($this->view->form->isValid($_POST))
        {
            $report = new Model_Users();

            $this->view->results = $report->reportProductivity(
                $this->view->form->getStartDate('yyy-MM-dd'), 
                $this->view->form->getEndDate('yyy-MM-dd')
            );
        }

    }
```

Is this some form of Model class?

Comment: `Jobs_Form_Report_Productivity` is the name of class

Comment: It seems like a form class. Normally it would be in `application/modules/job/form/report/Productivity.php`

Answer (score 2):

ZF1 uses PEAR namespacing (note the underscores), each underscore becomes a directory separator and the last part of the classname is usually the name of the file  typically something like 'Productivity.php', so Jobs_From_Report_Productivity should be located in Jobs/Form/Report in a file called 'Productivity.php'. 
Since the classname you are looking for does not start with 'Application_', my suggestion is that it is a module namespace called 'jobs', so you are probably looking for 'application/modules/jobs/forms/report/Productivity.php, 
otherwise it could be in the library directory as library/jobs/forms/report/Productivity.php. 
Of course, its completey possible to do some weird and wonderful things with the locations that ZF1 uses to locate classes.

Comment: It's partially valid answer and OP might find it confusing. Read about autoloader and default name spaces. The path might be corresponding to directory structure but in this case directory name is "forms".

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework use Zend_Loader_Autoloader to load classes that are called but not found in the script scoope. When a class that isn't found is called the autoloader kicks in and find and include the class file in few simple steps.

1) Converts all the _ (underscore sign) into / (slash) in the class name.
Example: Zend_Loader_Autoloade becomes Zend/Loader/Autoloader

2) The suffix .php is appended to the end of the converted string and it becomes: Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php

3) Checks if the "Zend_" name space (name space as class prefix and not PHP5.3 namespace) is registered with the autoloader. If the name space is registered then the autoloader will issue: include Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php.

4) If the class is found it returns it and the script continues. If class not found based on the configuration throws and exception or error.

PRE-CONDITION: The file Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php should be in the PHP include path for the current script.

Therefore, Jobs_Form_Report_Productivity will correspond to Jobs/Form/Report/Productivity.php and it will be found in one (or more) of the include paths. Find the include paths with PHP's: get_include_path(). Most of the times (in ZF1) the include path(s) is/are set in the index.php file in the public directory of the Zend Framework application.

See: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md as the guys from PHP-FIG made this autoloading approach a standard "PSR-O"

Hope this helps :)